# Facebook android Release key has issue

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

- I am trying to register android app on facebook
- Genereated key hash :
- During the registration process I get stuck at the release key hash field. Because I dont have one.. App is not published yet ,it has a long way to go...

[image]

Comment: I think you can put anything in there for now, and you can always change it later in your app settings. Thanks for the feedback though, I'll let the team know about this behavior.